# querySelector vs. getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, getelementbyid, queryselector

I have heard that `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are new methods to select DOM elements. How do they compare to the older methods, `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName` in terms of performance and browser support?

How does the performance compare to using jQuery's query selector?

What is the difference between `querySelector` and `getElementById`?
When should we use `querySelector` instead of `getElementById`? Is there any example which is not possible using `getElementById`?

Comment: Define better. They're almost entirely different.

Comment: This is like asking "is a single-size spanner better than an adjustable spanner?" The answer is: they are more powerful and more flexible, and so on many occasions superior, but `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName` are still ideal for the purposes their names describe.

Comment: If you're asking specifically about the places where they overlap, then it all depends. `qS` and `qSA` may be slower (or maybe not). `qSA` has broader support overall than `gEBCN`. `gEBCN` returns a "live list" and `qSA` does not.

Comment: Oh, and `qS/qSA` can be used from any element context, but `gEBI` can only be used from the `document` context.

Comment: `getElementById` matches the `id` attributes to find DOM nodes, while `querySelector` searches by selectors. So for an invalid selector e.g `<div id="1"></div>`, `getElementById('1')` would work while `querySelector('#1')` would fail, unless you tell it to match the `id` attribute (e.g `querySelector('[id="1"]')`.

Comment: Just an FYI for anyone reading this, but `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are fully supported now. https://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Comment: The `good` thing about `querySelector` is that it returns the first element found. Unlike some of these other methods that return multiple elements.

Answer (score 215):

"Better" is subjective.

`querySelector` is the newer feature.

`getElementById` is better supported than `querySelector` (not that it matters today, some years after this answer was originally written).

`querySelectorAll` is better supported than `getElementsByClassName` but `querySelectorAll` gives you a **static** node list while `getElementsByClassName` gives you a **live** node list.

`querySelector` lets you find elements with rules that can't be expressed with `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName`

You need to pick the appropriate tool for any given task.

(In the above, for `querySelector` read `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll`).

Comment: querySelector support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Comment: Very good answer and here are some [benchmark tests](http://jsben.ch/8tEs3)

Comment: Why does querySelector blindly choose the first matching element as it goes down the html code instead of doing breadth-first search and choosing the first matching element that is closest in depth to the parent???

Answer (score 53):

The functions `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName` are very specific, while `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are more elaborate. My guess is that they will actually have a worse performance.

Also, you need to check for the support of each function in the browsers you are targetting. The newer it is, the higher probability of lack of support or the function being "buggy".

Comment: There are several archived versions: https://web.archive.org/web/20160108040024/http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector But the test is actually very old (2010), so the result might be very different with more modern engines.

Comment: The archived page actually is dynamic and allows you to re-run the test on your current browser. querySelectorAll is still slower by reportedly about 37% on my browser. (Chrome 71 - https://vgy.me/TwGL3o.png) It's also worth noting that getElementById returns a live result, meaning that if you change the DOM , the change will be reflected by the result obtained by getElementByID (if in scope) whereas the nodelist returned by querySelectorAll is a snapshot, e.g. as things were at the time the call was made, the result will not reflect subsequent changes to the DOM.

Comment: `nodelist ... is not live` can you provide documentation for that? @W.Prins both methods return the `Element` type.

Comment: Ah, I see I made a typo, please accept my apologies!  I should have written "getElementsByClassName" where I wrote "getElementByID", e.g. it is getElementsByClassName (and similar) which returns a live resultset".  Indeed both getElementsByClassName and querySelectorAll returns a NodeList, but in the former case it's live, and in the latter it's a snapshot.

Comment: This being live in case of GetElementsByClassName is described here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#getelementsbyclassname  Elsewhere (in https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall) it is written: "The NodeList object returned by the querySelectorAll() method must be static, not live ([DOM-LEVEL-3-CORE], section 1.1.1). Subsequent changes to the structure of the underlying document must not be reflected in the NodeList object."