# How do I select a node within a template string in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Create an element and pass it an innerHTML string.

```js
let mydiv = document.createElement('div');
mydiv.innerHTML = "<div> <p>Intro</p> </div> <div id='greet'> <p>Hello Example</p> </div>";
console.log(mydiv.getElementByID("greet"))
```

.. How do I get the element with id='greet'?

```
mydiv.getElementbyID('greet')   //doesn't work.
```

Comment: Did you try: `document.getElementById('greet')`?

Comment: You can't use `getElementById` on an element.

Comment: I created a snippet for you and the console told me immediately what the error is

Comment: did you want to create new element(div) using javascript?

Comment: :)  Thanks! `getElementById("greet")` wont do it. The question highlights the difference between using DOM getElementById() and the querySelector().

Answer (score 0):

Assuming u have jquery

```
$(mydiv).find("#greet");
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code, you can use [Element.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) instead

You do have a few issues

1. misspelling getElementByID - should be getElementById
2. you cannot use `Element.getElementById` - you can use document.getElementById after inserting the new div into the DOM

**querySelector**

```js
let mydiv = document.createElement('div');
mydiv.innerHTML = "<div> <p>Intro</p> </div> <div id='greet'> <p>Hello Example</p> </div>";
console.log(mydiv.querySelector("#greet"))
```

Or jQuery:

```js
let $myDiv =$('<div/>');
$myDiv.html("<div> <p>Intro</p> </div> <div id='greet'> <p>Hello Example</p> </div>");
console.log($myDiv.find("#greet"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydiv.querySelector('#greet')
```

This is one very **subtle** difference between these selectors. With query selector, we can query string templates. Inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848289/javascript-queryselector-vs-getelementbyid).

Comment: I beat you by 5 minutes :)

Comment: yeah. That was fast! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way,

```
for (var child = mydiv.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
   if(child.id == "greet") {
      console.log(child);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementById is on document and not on a node.
So you can always use queryselector like this.

```
let mydiv = document.createElement('div');
mydiv.innerHTML = "<div> <p>Intro</p> </div> <div id='greet'> <p>Hello Example</p> </div>";
console.log(mydiv.querySelector("#greet"));
```

Comment: My bad, Didn't the same when I started typing my answer.
Sucks that I took nearly 5 minutes to answer the question.