# Difference between using document.querySelector('#id') and document.getElementById('id')

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner in javascript and I have seen many people using `document.querySelector('#id')`  and some people using `document.getElementById('id')` for grabbing the html element with the id.
Please answer weather these are same or we have to use them differently.

Comment: Their results are the same; their speed is implementation-dependent. Related: [Javascript querySelector vs. getElementById](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26848289/4642212).

Comment: in this case of use they do the same. but querySelector methods are more useful, has JS evolve

Comment: Using `querySelector` you can select anything, like elements by name, elements with class name and elements with ids. In above `getElementById` is specifically used for selecting element by ID. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById.

Comment: `getelementbyid` only selects id but queryselector selects anything, thats it xD

Comment: I'm expecting getElementById to be faster by some orders of magnitude, but still resulting in absolute numbers that in 99.9% of cases make absolutely no practical difference.

Answer (score 0):

Quite significant difference is that .getElementById is only applicable on document level while .querySelector can be applied on element level. I.e querySelector allows you to control where to start traversing while getElementById will always traverse from the document root. This means that that querySelector does not require an id to unique within the whole document but only to be unique within a node.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I think a significant difference between them is; getElementById effect both on element and content of this,but quarySelector only effect element.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!