# Which DOM selector to use in selecting HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-frontend

There are various DOM selector like `querySelector` , `querySelectorAll`, `getElementById`, `getELementsByClassName` and many more. But my question is when and where we should use which selector during programming. Are there any best practices that tells to specifically use the selector for this task.

Comment: I think `querySelectorAll` covers them all. So if you need to learn one (and you needn't) then this is it

Comment: Each has their own purpose. Check out the MDN documentation for them. Here's [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). The rest are available in the links on the left, or by searching.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [querySelector vs. getElementById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848289/queryselector-vs-getelementbyid)

Comment: What about in context of static node and live node . Is it something to worry about in projects

Comment: Why have you tagged jQuery?

Comment: this is the historical evolution of javascript, with the merging of concepts between css and JS

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector` returns one (the first) element found, and uses a CSS style selector.

`querySelectorAll` returns a node list (which, depending on your browser support, you may need to convert to an array to work with), and uses the same CSS style selector.

`getElementById` takes a string and only finds an element that matches that ID (IDs should be unique).

`getElementsByClassName` takes a string and matches like ID, but can return an array like list of elements.

If you're familiar with CSS selectors, you can use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` for almost every situation. The performance is pretty close to the `getElement*` ones, but they're much more powerful. For example, if you wanted to get a `span` that is the first child of a `class` in an `id`, you could do `.querySelector('#id .class span')` instead of chaining together `.getElementById('id').getElementsByClass('class')[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any specific rules on what to use when but I'll share my opinions regarding each method:

- getElementById: Can be used for elements that only exist once and have an id
- getElementsByClassName: For elements that have a class name that can be queried
- querySelector: Use it when you want to query one specific element
- querySelectorAll: same as `querySelector` but for multiple elements

caniuse.com is a great resource to check browser support.

Comment: Honestly, `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName` are both very commonly used. Also, there's no official statement saying that those elements are legacy.

Comment: You're right, adjusted the answer!