# Get element content in angular (alternative to .html() in jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've got this element:

```
<span id="tag_span"> {{ selectedSection }} </span>
```

And I want to get its content from controller, which is `{{ selectedSection }}`. I can get the element like this:

```
angular.element('#tag_span');
```

but don't know how to get what inside of it. Any ideas?

P.S. `document.getElementById` won't work in the case so there's no need to suggest it.

EDIT: No jQuery allowed.

Comment: It might be bad idea to pass HTML from controller. Are you sure you want it? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230242/angular-element-vs-document-getelementbyid-or-jquery-selector-with-spin-busy-c

Comment: I hope you are not creating duplicate id's because that is the only reason I know of why `getElementById` will not work. Duplicating ID's will make it impossible to validate your page and cause the page to run in quirks mode on all browsers. The value of the ID attribute, if assigned, must be unique for every element that has an ID on the page. Just a warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your all html elements are properties of $scope, so you could easily access the content via `$scope.selectedSection` . Your controller function definition must have a scope injection like `function controller($scope)`, that is all.

Comment: Not exactly my case, but it helped me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You get the value by $scope.selectedSection from your controller.

If you need the get html inside the span element use

```
angular.element($('#tag_span')).html();
```

You need to reference the jquery before angular js like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/angular/angular.js"></script>
```