# Button click is not a function error in angular controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to build a file upload component and I am getting the error :button.click is not a function. Why is that?

```
<form name="uploadForm">
        <div layout-gt-sm="row">
            <input id="fileInput" type="file" class="ng-hide">
            <md-input-container>
                <input id="textInput" type="text" >
            </md-input-container>
            <md-button id="uploadButton">Choose file</md-button>
            <md-button id="saveButton"  ng-click="$ctrl.uploadVideoFile($event)" >Upload</md-button>
        </div>
    </form>

    viewUploadModule.controller('viewUploadController', function ($location) {
        var self = this;

        self.$onInit = function (scope,element,location) {

            var input = angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')); 
            var button =  angular.element(document.querySelector('#uploadButton'));
            var textInput =  angular.element(document.querySelector('#textInput'));
        }

         button.click(function (e) {
                    input.click();
                });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use button.click, instead call the function in **`ng-click`**

```
<md-button id="uploadButton" ng-click="yourfunction()">Choose file</md-button>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was using it before without ng-click  and it was working fine. I need to trigger a click event from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
button.click(function (e) {
                    input.click();
                });
```

To this:

```
self.uploadVideoFile= function (e) {
                        input.click();
                    }
```

Comment: Getting the same error : input.click is not a function

Comment: Try this: `document.getElementById('fileInput').click()` instead of `input.click()`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap Dom element with `angular.element`.You must only use Dom element.

`document.getElementById('fileInput').click()`

[executable code](https://jsbin.com/jisazi/edit?html,js,console,output)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230242/angular-element-vs-document-getelementbyid-or-jquery-selector-with-spin-busy-c) is helpful too.