# setting focus to angular elements inside ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I want to copy the value from `vm.foo` to `vm.bar` (that works) and then set focus to `vm.bar` (that does not work).

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.foo" id="foo" >
<button ng-click="vm.baa=vm.foo; angular.element('#bar').focus();"></button>

<input type="text" ng-model="vm.bar" id="bar" >
```

How come `angular.element('#bar').focus()` is not working in this situation?

Comment: I didn't know `angular.element('#bar');` was a viable method of accessing DOM elements.  Are you sure that `angular.element` can access an element with id `bar`?

Comment: @JarekKulikowski if jQuery loaded before angularjs, then yes, it is possible

Comment: In that case perhaps replacing `angular.element` with `$` would work.

Comment: It works fine as long as you have it in your angular controller, but put it into the html page and it no longer works.  (and $ gives error, I dont use jquery)

Comment: things like this belong in a directive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom directive to emit an event.

```
app.directive('focusOn', () => {
   return (scope, elem, attr) => {
      scope.$on(attr.focusOn, (e) => {
          elem[0].focus();
      });
   };
});
```

Usage:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.foo">

<button ng-click="vm.baa=vm.foo; vm.changeFocus();"></button>

<input type="text" ng-model="vm.bar" focus-on="myFocusEvent">
```

and then in your controller

```
vm.changeFocus = () => {
    $scope.$broadcast('myFocusEvent');
};
```

> Notice that I'm using arrow functions instead of named functions

Answer (score 0):

I found this [Accessing Dom elements in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18921274/8298495)

so in our case that would be

```
<button ng-click="vm.baa=vm.foo; angular.element(document.querySelector('#bar')).focus();"></button>
```

I wonder if that fixes your problem.
Actually I would change it to

```
ng-click="vm.baa=vm.foo; setFocus();"
```

and in the controller

```
vm.setFocus = function() {
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#bar'));
}
```

Comment: Sorry - no effect at all. Even when I put this into the controller it does nothing.

Comment: I find that I need to use `setTimeout` to do `focus` otherwise it doesn't work for me either; I think it has to be done in the controller.

Comment: I think you might be right, I will give it a few more tries.