# angular.element selector vs jquery selector

Tags: jquery, angularjs, performance

Which selector is faster in an angular 1.x application? I have Jquery included and have been using both in my application as in below:

```
var paneWidth = angular.element('.side-nav').width();
var paneWidth = jquery('.side-nav').width();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230242/angular-element-vs-document-getelementbyid-or-jquery-selector-with-spin-busy-c

Comment: The biggest difference is that angular.element is a jQuery alias, and returns a jQuery (or jQuery lite) object.

Answer (score 0):

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery
>   function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to
>   AngularJS's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or jqLite.

[docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: Ok got it about aliases.Nevertheless , can i conclude that there would be no impact in speed, irrespective of the selectors being used ?

Comment: Direct call of the jQuery should be a little faster

Answer (score 0):

```
var paneWidth = jquery('.side-nav').width();
```

From the above code if you didn't include jquery in your angularjs code it doesn't works it through angular errors. To use jQuery, simply ensure it is loaded before the angular.js file.

```
var paneWidth = angular.element('.side-nav').width();
```

From the above code, angular.element delegates to AngularJS's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or jqLite. Its already pre build in the angularjs code

**Which is Faster?**

Sure, jQuery is faster than angular.element().