# what is the equivalent of $('#xxl') selector of jquery in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code,that shows a modal with this code using jquery:

```
$('#myModal').modal({'show':true});
```

but with angular.js not works. what is the equivalent of  `$('#myModal')` using angular.js?

```
// not works for me
angular.element("#myModal")
```

Comment: can you `console.log(angular.element("#myModal"))`

Comment: Don't do it this way;   Manipulating the DOM should only be a last resort when you can't get AngularJs to do what you want any other way (extremely rare).  In case of a modal, an `ng-show` should be all you need.

Comment: You need to use angular bootstrap directive https://aashishkoirala.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/angular-bootstrap-modal/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular.element vs document.getElementById or jQuery selector with spin (busy) control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230242/angular-element-vs-document-getelementbyid-or-jquery-selector-with-spin-busy-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector` to get the dom element and then use `angular.element`

```
var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('#myModal'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try by injecting $document

```
var elem = $document('#myModal');
```

In your case, you also do this little change to make your program run.

```
var elem = angular.element(document).find('#myModal');
```